# What is the JMX mbean to get Read count , write count on a table for cassandra version 3.11.4

Tags: cassandra

What is the JMX mbean to get Read count , write count on a table for cassandra version **3.11.4**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract it from the `ReadLatency` and `WriteLatency` metrics that have an attribute called `Count` that represents number of read or write operations correspondingly. The metric name is `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=<ks_name>,scope=<table_name>,name=ReadLatency` for reads, or `org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=Table,keyspace=<ks_name>,scope=<table_name>,name=WriteLatency` for writes.

See [Cassandra metrics documentation](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/operating/metrics.html) for more details.