# Which Cassandra metrics expose the reads and writes per second?

Tags: cassandra, prometheus

I have a v3.9 unmanaged Cassandra server.
In preparation to migrating to another system, I'm interested in discovering how many reads and writes per second (or day) we're doing.
I've exported the metrics to Prometheus using JMX, but I can't discover a metric that counts the reads/writes.
This answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/58373711) recommends something, but I can't find it in my metrics, not sure whether I'm not looking in the right place or my server is too old.

Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: A friendly reminder that this site is for getting help with coding, algorithm, or programming language problems so I voted to have your post moved to [DBA Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra). For future reference, you should post DB admin/ops questions on https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/ask?tags=cassandra. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The answer you linked is correct, the read / write latency histograms include a count. You should also be able to see the same count within the `nodetool cfstats` output.

Check if you see a read count / write count on the `nodetool cfstats` if you do, then it will be within the JMX.

For reference, this count starts at zero when a node is restarted, so within a cluster, the number of reads / writes per day you would have to calculate per node, and then add those together.

Comment: Could you provide an example on how the key looks in `/metrics`? Just to be sure I'm not missing it

Comment: @Nitz : org.apache.cassandra.metrics{type=Table, keyspace=system, scope=sstable_activity, name=WriteLatency}[]Count: 702847. - taken from a JMX dump of a node.

Answer (score 1):

Look at the counts reported by the metrics called `Latency` of type `ClientRequest`. The specific mbeans are:

```
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Read,name=Latency
org.apache.cassandra.metrics:type=ClientRequest,scope=Write,name=Latency
```

These metrics report the number of read/write requests per second on the coordinator nodes which is equivalent to the read/write requests from the client application(s).

Note that `Latency` metrics record both `Timer` and `Counter` which track (1) the duration of the latency and (2) the number of requests. Cheers!